# Removing duplicate items in the list and getting their number Dart Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, duplicates

I have a list of objects and I want to remove duplicates and also add the number of removed items to the remaining item in the list.

```
var data = [
  {
    name: "book",
    qty: 1
  },
  {
    name: "book"
    qty: 1
  },
  {
    name: "book",
    qty: 1
  },
  {
    name: "pen",
    qty: 1
  },
  {
    name: "pen",
    qty: 1
  },
 
];
```

The result should be something like this

```
[{name: "book", qty: 3},{name: "pen",qty: 2}],
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the collection library
Import the collection library by typing

`import 'package:collection/collection.dart';`

and then use the groupby function to group the items together, Here's an example code

```
var consolidatedData = groupBy(data, (obj) => obj['name'])
      .values
      .map((group) => {
            'name': group.first['name'],
            'qty': group.length,
          })
      .toList();
```

I hope this helps